# Map joomla to an old database

Tags: joomla, joomla1.7

I  have a database which I used to install joomla 1.7. Unfortunately I lost the Joomla folder which I had kept on htdocs. I want to install another Joomla site and use the old database. I have tried to install another Joomla site and connect to the old database I had used, but it seems that a new site is being created. Is there any way I can map the Joomla website to the database? I don't want to have to create another website.

Comment: once you've gone through a new set up, check the config file and make adjust to table name etc in there.

Comment: @KutF that is what I have done the prefix on the database is bak_o142k_.I have changed the prefix on the joomla config file but it is showing the new database.

Comment: in phpmyadmin try renaming new db to a different name and then changing backup to the currently used name. also check if there is some caching issues?

Comment: @KutF thanks.I have succeeded.

Comment: i'll add as an answer then, if you'll accept it. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in phpmyadmin try renaming new db to a different name and then changing backup to the currently used name. also check if there is some caching issues?

Answer (score 1):

Install fresh joomla and make following changes in configuration.php to use the old database.

newjoomladirectory/configuration.php

```
public $dbtype = 'mysqli';

public $user = '**dbusername**';   // this will be database user name of old db

public $password = 'mypassword'; // your password to access old datbase

public $db = 'jml17';   // change it to old db

public $dbprefix = 'j17_'; // change it to your old db prefix.
```

This will connect you to your old database.